# Android Repeat notification every day

Tags: android, notifications

I want repeat my notification every day, I've do this code, whithout errors but It doesn't repeat my notification every day...
Where is the problem ?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tick)
        .setWhen(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");


Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);


NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
manager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you should use the `AlarmManager`. The following links will help you.

[Android Fundamentals: Scheduling Recurring Tasks](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-scheduling-recurring-tasks--mobile-5788)

[Repeat Alarm Example In Android Using AlarmManager](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

system killed the process. You may take measures to keep it alive